# Aggregated one hot encoding

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I have collected hour-by-hour data about weather forecast. The features I have collected are numerical - 'temperature', 'precipitation' as well as categorical - 'weather_forecast' (e.g. 'sunny', 'fair', 'cloudy', 'rain', 'heavy rain' etc.).
I need to create daily weather forecast statistics. Whilst for numerical feature it is easy (min, max, mean, std etc.) I am struggling a bit what to do with categorical data.
I was thinking about one-hot-encoding for 'weather_forecast' feature for each hour and then sum these values together.

For example, for the following data:

```
hour      weather_forecast
8:00         sunny
9:00         sunny
10:00        sunny
11:00        cloudy
12:00        rain
13:00        cloudy
```

in one hot encoding

```
       sunny     cloudy     rain
8:00      1         0         0
9:00      1         0         0
10:00     1         0         0
11:00     0         1         0
12:00     0         0         1
13:00     0         1         0
```

I would get statistics like

```
sunny: 3
cloudy: 2
rain: 1
```

which might get me an aggregated statistics about the weather during a day.

I am wondering if there are any pitfalls/issues with this approach or things to be aware of. Does this encoding has a name (I couldn't find it on the web).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an "encoding": you haven't encoded the data, you've summarized it.  You could do so as easily simply by counting the occurrences in the `weather_forecast` column.

Comment: What I mean by encoding is that I have encoded categorical values into features and then summarized them. If I just counted the occurrences in the weather_forecast column, as you suggested, I would have to turn (encode) this information into features somehow to get my weather forecast daily statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encoding finished when you applied one-hot encoding to the weather_forecast. Sums shows you just number of hours when the weather was sunny, cloudy etc..

If you divide your statistics in total number of hours you'll receive percentages of weather types during a time period, a day for example. Nothing special issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is issue in this which is called dummy variable trap for that you have to remove the 1 dummy variable column for example in this case you have to remove sunny column to avoid yourself from dummy variable trap

```
#creating dummies of independent variables
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

#avoiding dummy variable trap
#to avoid redundant data but the python libraries are taking care of it but sometimes 
you have to manually remove it
X = X[:, 1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is a pandas DF, then try this

```
df.sum()
```

This should give the sum of all columns for the dataset which should give you the result you're expecting.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Hope this is helpful and what you’re looking for. Let me know